# SQL query two PIVOT columns combine

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, window-functions

```
select pvtMonth.CardName, [1] as [Jan Sales], [2] as [Feb Sales], [3] as [Mar Sales], [4] as [Apr Sales], [5] as [May Sales], 
[6] as [Jun Sales], [7] as [Jul Sales], [8] as [Aug Sales], [9] as [Sep Sales], [10] as [Oct Sales], [11] as [Nov Sales], [12] as [Dec Sales] from 
(
select X.CardName, SUM(X.[Total Sales S$]) as [Sales $] , X.Month from Data X group by X.CardName ,X.Month
) X PIVOT 
(
    sum(X.[Sales $])
    FOR [Month]
    IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] )
) AS pvtMonth order by pvtMonth.CardName asc
```

[image]

now i need add one more called "Jan Gp" the column name is "X.Gp". How to update my query. I need the result set like below

[image]

Comment: SQL Server, or something else? Also, I feel like there are plenty duplicates of this; did you search first?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using conditional aggregation instead of the `pivot` syntax. It is much more flexible (and at least as efficient). You seem to want something like:

```
select 
    cardName,
    sum(case when month = 1 then [Total Sales S$]  end) [Jan Sales $],
    sum(case when month = 1 then [Total Sales SGP] end) [Jan Sales GP],
    sum(case when month = 2 then [Total Sales S$]  end) [Feb Sales $],
    sum(case when month = 2 then [Total Sales SGP] end) [Feb Sales GP],
    ...
from data
group by cardName
```

Comment: Just so you know, the "conditional aggregation" is known as a "CROSSTAB".

Comment: @JeffModen How to do can help ?

Comment: @GMB 's answer above is correct.  It uses a CROSSTAB, which is frequently faster than a PIVOT (especially for two column Pivots like what you asked for), allows for a whole lot more customization, and easily allows for row totals and column totals.